# Can I upload CSV file to MySQL database without deleting "\" backslash which is placed in CSV file using php

Tags: php, mysql, backslash, fgetcsv

**Csv file has been uploaded to database but backslash() is automatically getting deleted when I upload CSV file to database.
I need that \ to be also uploaded in the database.
For eg : I need to add the folder location into database like C:\Users\Others\Desktop\Gips report but it shows like C:UsersOthersDesktopGips report**

```
 $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {

        $file = fopen($filename, "r");

        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",", '"' , '"' )) !== FALSE)

  {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO csvfile(id,Projectnumber,Projectfolder,e0id) VALUES ('".$emapData[0]."','".$emapData[1]."','".$emapData[2]."','".$emapData[3]."')";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo "CSV File has been successfully Imported";
        }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's almost impossible for us to help you unless you show us a bit of code, or at least explain how you read your .csv file and INSERT its rows to your table. And, please show us a few lines of your file, including some with the `\\` characters you want preserved in your table.  Please [edit] your question or ask another.

Comment: Use prepared statements. Then there is no need to escape anything.

Comment: hi Jones i have edited and added a bit of code

Comment: Hi markus but iam using array to import all the datas in file to database so if i use prepared statement then i cannot fetch all datas from csv file to database right?

Comment: Of course you can. Prepared statements and parameters don't prevent you from doing that